# SQL Server lost tables and stored procedures when reinstalled

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL server database containing 7 tables, 15 stored procedures, and 2 views I detached it and copied it then I reset my computer and I installed SQL server software again.**when** I attached the database I didn't get my tables and stored procedures I got many unknown tables whose names start with mdm.xxx as shown in the attached picture

[image]

Comment: Attached the wrong database maybe?

Comment: yes, I don't know from where these tables came